# How to add DbSet<EntityName> to a context that is generated dynamically with Codedom?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, codedom

I am generating entities dynamically using Codedom. I also don't have a hardcoded context class as part of the solution. That is, I am also generating the contexts at run time using Codedom. I am doing this so every generated entity has its own context. I am running into a problem with writing the Codedom code for the context class. As part of the context, I need to write in the DbSet property so the generated entity can be part of the model for the context. More specifically, I need the following line in my generated context:

```
public DbSet<EntityName> EntityNames { get; set; }
```

where EntityName is the name of the entity class type I have created, and EntityNames is just that name with an 's' on the end. For example, I might create an Employee entity, so I would like to generate a context with:

```
public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

To do this I am writing a method that returns this CodeMemberProperty. It knows to write Employee/Employees because I pass in the name of the entity. That's fine. The method looks like this so far:

```
public static CodeMemberProperty HardCodeDbSet(string contextName)
{
    string entityName = contextName.Substring(0, contextName.Length - 7);
    CodeMemberProperty prop = new CodeMemberProperty();
    prop.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Final;
    prop.Name = entityName + "s";
    prop.Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(DbSet<>));
    return prop;
}
```

The reason for this line:

```
string entityName = contextName.Substring(0, contextName.Length - 7);
```

is that I make the name of the generated context the corresponding entity name + "Context", so in that line I am removing "Context" to get back the entityName. Anyway, that's not really relevant. The line that's giving me trouble is the type one:

```
prop.Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(DbSet<>));
```

This just gives me:

```
DbSet<>
```

But I need:

```
DbSet<EntityName>
```

If I try to write anything inside the angle brackets I get an error saying that it can't resolve the symbol. For example I would like to write:

```
prob.Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(DbSet<entityType>));
```

And I could just make

```
Type entityType
```

a parameter of this method, but it doesn't like that.

Does anyone know a way around this? I thought it would be a lot simpler to code this, but Codedom isn't as cooperative as I thought sometimes...

Comment: Why generating the Context? Have a look at [DbModelBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbmodelbuilder(v=vs.113).aspx). Also get some [infos for types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx) Also: Why one Context per Entity? What do you want to achive? What is your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're basically asking for here, if we go to the heart of the matter, is how to use reflection to get the Type of a closed generic type. This doesn't have anything to do with CodeDom or EntityFramework specifically.

As you mentioned, using `typeof(DbSet<>)` (or `List<>`, or anything) will give you the "open generic type", meaning the one that specific generic types are based on. From here, you can use the method [`MakeGenericType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx) to create the specific closed generic type:

```
var openType = typeof(DbSet<>);
var closedType = openType.MakeGenericType(entityType);
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining it well! It's clear to me now what the issue was actually about.

Comment: Sometimes it's hard, especially when using complicated libraries like CodeDom or EF, to separate the forest from the trees. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the open generic `DbSet<>` and make it closed, like so:

```
typeof(DbSet<>).MakeGenericType(entityType)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :) I accepted the other one because he was first haha